# Netbeans Window Groups w/Annotations

Tags: java, annotations, netbeans-platform

I've seen tutorials and questions like the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922179/creating-window-groups-on-netbeans-platform
- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/creating_a_window_group

Those refer to the old ways of doing this via xml files, etc. is there a way to accomplish this but with annotations?

I tried with annotations as follows:

```
@TopComponent.Description(
        preferredID = "ChatTopComponent",
        //iconBase="SET/PATH/TO/ICON/HERE", 
        persistenceType = TopComponent.PERSISTENCE_NEVER
)
@TopComponent.Registration(mode = "output", openAtStartup = false,
        roles = {"Game"})
```

Thanks in advance!

I'm using Platform version RELEASE80

**Update**

Added a sample project with the issue as requested [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1oCYY8ny-i1VGhYV010eWdPcm8/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Could you provide your build configuration? I've tested this exactly like you here and it's building for me.

Comment: What do you mean by configuration? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Your Ant or Maven configuration to build your application. It would be perfect if you could provide a small example project to further demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Will add it as an update in a sec. Will try a sample project and provide it ASAP.

Comment: Sample project provided.

Comment: Well, that builds without errors on my machine. I am using Netbeans 8.0.1, the bundled Maven 3.0.5, Java 1.8.0_05 on Windows 8.1 here. Did you try to clean your local Maven repository? Which Maven version are you using? I'm a little bit puzzled to be honest.

Comment: I made it build on mine as well, is just not finding the defined roles. I think that last part is misleading. I have Windows 7, Netbeans 8.0.2, Java 1.8.0_25, Maven 3.2.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69682/discussion-between-javydreamercsw-and-padde).